# Error loading carreer object with angular, server error - gets undefined, null

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to get an specif carreer from my database in mongo under the url /carreras/:id, the id is ok, but when angular goes to the server gets a null.

[image: Print of log in chrome]

I tried to to change the response from my backend in node, changin res.json({
ok: true,
carrera: carrera
}) 
by res.send(carrera)

carrera.service.ts

```
export class CarreraService {
private urlCarrera = 'http://localhost:3000/carrera';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getCarrera(id: string) {
return this.http.get(this.urlCarrera + '/' + id).pipe(
  map((resp: any) => {
    return resp;
  })
);
```

}

carreras.component.ts

```
public id;
carreraBd: any;

constructor(public carreraServ: CarreraService,
public router: Router, public actRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.id = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.traerCarrera();
}

traerCarrera() {

try {
  const traerCarrera = this.carreraServ.getCarrera(this.id);
  console.log(this.id);

  traerCarrera.subscribe(
    (resp: any) => {
      console.log(resp);
      this.carreraBd = resp;
    });
  console.log(this.carreraBd);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);

}
```

}

backend

carrerasController.js

```
exports.getCarrera = (req, res) => {

var id = req.params.id;

Carrera.findById(id, (err, carrera) => {

    if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            ok: false,
            err: err
        });
    }

    if (!carrera) {
        res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            err: err
        });
    }


    res.send(carrera);

});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cors issue. 
quick fix:

1. install cors in backend

   npm i cors --save

2.

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors()) // use like this.
```

Comment: Thanks man, i try to fix the cors by other ways but only this works.